# Explode multiple json files using python

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read multiple json files from a folder, explode them using dataframe and write it onto a location as delta.

Below is my sample json file:

```
'{"result": [{"approval": "Approved", "assigned_to": "", "assignment_group": "Business Requests", "opened_at": "08/10/2016 08:36:35", "opened_by": "Kay", "priority": "4 - Low", "sys_created_by": "p1843591@production.local", "sys_created_on": "08/10/2016 08:36:35", "urgency": "3 - Low"}, {"approval": "Approved", "assigned_to": "", "assignment_group": "Business Requests", "opened_at": "08/10/2016 10:13:11", "opened_by": "Alan", "priority": "4 - Low", "sys_created_on": "08/10/2016 10:13:11", "urgency": "3 - Low"}, ................
```

But Im getting the below error:
AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(Result)`

Any suggestion or help to resolve this error ?

I am using the below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import glob
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.json.allowEmptyString.enabled", True)
for file in glob.glob(f"/dbfs/mnt/landing/item/2023*/*.json"):
    file = file[5:]
    df = spark.read.option('multiline',True).json(file)
    df_exp = df.select(explode(col("result")).alias('Result')).select('Result.*')
    df_explode = df_exp.drop_duplicates()
    df_explode.write.format('delta').mode('append').option('inferSchema',True).save('/mnt/landing/finalitem/')
```

Comment: Im not aware of it, pls can you help

Comment: Why are you using `file = file[5:]`?

Comment: to remove /dbfs, and pick file from /mnt/landing...

Comment: @JonSG my intentions is rather the opposite, but i understand your impression.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula - Yes Im using Azure Databricks

Comment: Any help plssss. Stuck on this and unable to move forward

Comment: @iroh I have tried this code

Comment: from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer, col
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSONExplode").getOrCreate()
json_file_path = "/FileStore/tables/sample020202.json"
df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json(json_file_path)
df_exp = df.select(explode_outer(col("result")).alias('Result')).select('Result.*')
df_exp.show()
df_explode = df_exp.dropDuplicates()
delta_destination_path = "/FileStore/tables/finalitem"
df_explode.write.format('delta').mode('append').option('inferSchema', True).save(delta_destination_path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message **"AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types.
Attribute: ArrayBuffer(Result)"** means that you are trying to use the explode function on a column that is not structured like a list or an array.
Basically, you can only use the explode function on columns that have a specific structure, not just any column.

I have tried the below code:

I have used a JSON file as input for PySpark code to Read, Explode

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer, col
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JSONExplode").getOrCreate()
json_file_path = "/FileStore/tables/sample020202.json"
df = spark.read.option('multiline', True).json(json_file_path)
df_exp = df.select(explode_outer(col("result")).alias('Result')).select('Result.*')
df_exp.show()
df_explode = df_exp.dropDuplicates()
delta_destination_path = "/FileStore/tables/finalitem"
df_explode.write.format('delta').mode('append').option('inferSchema', True).save(delta_destination_path)
```

[image]

In the above code I have used `explode_outer` function on the "**result**" column

`explode_outer(col("result"))` to explode the elements within the array. The use of `explode_outer` suggests that it is designed to handle potential null values within the array.

To check if "**result**" column is correctly recognized as an array of structs, you can check the schema.
[image]